# Trying to retrive records from a server from current time to 1 hour ago time tamp in iso 8601 format

Tags: php

I'm retrieving bitcoin sales from a server in descending order, with a time stamp in ISO 8601 format.  I'm trying to get all the records from the current time to 1 hour minus the current time. I was looking at the DateTime class but did not see any metheds to compare two dates.

Comment: What do you want to compare? `DateTime` objects support `==`, `!=`, `<` and `>` operations so you can use those for basic comparisons.

Comment: You don't say how you're retrieving, DB, API???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DateTime has a method `modify()` , look at http://php.net/manual/it/datetime.modify.php

you can do somthing like:

```
$now = new DateTime();
$oneHourAgo = $now->modify("-1 hour");
```

and then run your query using ts > $oneHourAgo